# How to remove ^M from a text file and replace it with the next line

Tags: python, replace

So suppose I have a text file of the following contents:

```
Hello what is up. ^M
^M
What are you doing?
```

I want to remove the `^M` and replace it with the line that follows. So my output would look like:

```
Hello what is up. What are you doing?
```

How do I do the above in Python? Or if there's any way to do this with unix commands then please let me know.

Comment: Howcome your output doesn't replace the second `^M`?

Comment: a piece of cake if you are using vim :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
''.join(somestring.split(r'\r'))
```

or

```
somestring.replace(r'\r','')
```

This assumes you have carriage return characters in your string, and not the literal "^M". If it is the literal string "^M" then substiture r'\r' with "^M"

If you want the newlines gone then use r'\r\n'

This is very basic string manipulation in python and it is probably worth looking at some basic tutorials http://mihirknows.blogspot.com.au/2008/05/string-manipulation-in-python.html

And as the first commenter said its always helpful to give some indication of what you have tried so far, and what you don't understand about the problem, rather than asking for an straight answer.

Comment: I have tried all the methods mentioned here but none of the methods have worked. In the sense that it doesnt print 'Hello what is ip. What are you doing?' in one line. It prints it in two separate lines, which is what I dont want. The two lines are always separted by '^M'. I just need to remove this '^M' and merge the two statements that was separated by the '^M'

Comment: Then you should substitute the '\r' with '\r\n' as you have a carriage return (CR ^M, \r) char followed by a newline char (LF, \n).  In the environment you are using the LF (\n) is being interpreted hence the line break, but the ^M isn't hence it being printed as ^M. `somestring.replace(r'\r\n','')`

Comment: Since we want to replace a control character (written \r), why are you specifying it as a raw string with the r keyword? (r'\r').  This prevents python from interpreting the slash r properly and does not work. So, I think you meant to just have '\r' instead of r'\r' in the above. Cheers.

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
>>> mystring = mystring.replace("\r", "").replace("\n", "")
```

(where "mystring" contain your text)

Answer (score 0):

use `replace`

```
x='Hello what is up. ^M\
^M\
What are you doing?'

print x.replace('^M','') # the second parameter  insert what you want replace it with
```