# Handling \n vs ^M\n newlines with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, newline, separator

I was parsing a file containing key-value pairs like this:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    data = f.read()
    key_value_pairs = data.split(";\n")
```

then one day the delivered file had a different line terminator and someone changed that line which handles it to:

```
key_value_pairs = data.split(";^M\n")
```

Found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29907170/what-is-this-field-separator-m) which explains that the `^M` is an MS-DOS phenomenon.

Then [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12193252/4288043) claims the Windows terminator is `\r\n`, no mention being made of `^M\n`

As backround information, will mention that each element in that list `key_value_pairs` gets further split in another loop with `.split("=", 1)`

Am expecting future files to be have line termination unpredictably with or without the `^M` and trying to find a way to handle it without messy regex or string methods if they can be avoided.

Maybe the best bet is just to strip every `^M` out of the file in the beginning then treat them all as Unix files. That might be a bit dangerous for some base64 binary blocks in the file however.

Is there something in Python which will cleanly deal with those `^M` as the file gets opened?

Comment: What does "deal" mean here? Delete them? Convert them into something else?

Comment: If your `open` call really looks like that, Python should be converting `\r\n` to `\n` for you automatically. See the `newline` argument to the `open` function: https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#open

Comment: Split the file with newlines which are unpredictably with or without a `^M`

Comment: Have not yet seen a `\r` in the file and it does not look like `^M`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your link mentioned, `^M` is ASCII character 13, which should be read as `\r` by Python.

You could accomplish this simply with parsing an optional `\r` with `re.split`:

```
import re

data = 'split;\ntest;\r\nhere;\nanother;\r\nyay'

key_value_pairs = re.split(r';\r?\n', data)

# ['split', 'test', 'here', 'another', 'yay']
```

However, if it is a literal character `^` and `M`, use `re.split(r';\^M\n|;\n', data)`:

```
data = 'split;\ntest;^M\nhere;\nanother;^M\nyay'

key_value_pairs = re.split(r';\^M\n|;\n', data)

# ['split', 'test', 'here', 'another', 'yay']
```

Comment: Thanks @Krrr, I think it needs a little help in reading the `^M` as `\r`. Could you add an alternative regex which will also match `^M\n` if it is there instead of `\r\n`? Have done some experiments but can't get it to work.

Comment: As mentioned, I believe the character `^M` is read as `\r` in Python so that would be the correct way to parse it.  Relevant answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11755208/how-to-remove-m-from-a-text-file-and-replace-it-with-the-next-line - if it is a literal character `^` and `M`, use `re.split(r';\^M\n|;\n', data)`

Comment: Thanks that works perfectly with or without a `^M`. Why there was a 'literal' character I don't know, hopefully it won't happen again but if it does that regex seems to process it correctly.

Comment: It depends where the data passed through before it reached your script.  Some processing might have converted the ASCII character 13 to literal characters `^M` instead of the raw character.

Comment: Yes, and here that 'some processing' is probably before it reaches python, will mention it to the person who manages it. Something with ssh transfer of a file, am sure there is a bit which can go wrong.